# How to enable Full-Text Search on Azure SQL Edge for docker?

Tags: docker, azure-sql-database, apple-m1, azure-sql-server

I know I can follow something like [this](https://schwabencode.com/blog/2019/10/27/MSSQL-Server-2017-Docker-Full-Text-Search) to install FTS on SQL Server for Docker.

However, since I'm using an Arm machine (Apple Silicon / M1), I need to use Azure SQL Edge instead. SQL Edge has an announcement saying that it has FTS, but it's not there out of the box it seems. It acts like the normal SQL without the FTS component.

How am I supposed to add it?

Answer (score 2):

Was struggling with the same issue and was quite happy with using [Colima](https://github.com/abiosoft/colima) for emulating x86-64, unfortunately it didn't quite work with load of inserts from my integration tests.

Docker desktop for Mac is [now supporting Rosetta 2 for emulating x86-64 binaries](https://github.com/docker/roadmap/issues/384). If you have 4.16.0 version installed you can enable it in settings

[image]

I was able to build and run [this](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/blob/master/linux/preview/examples/mssql-agent-fts-ha-tools/Dockerfile) sql server with full text search enabled with `docker build --platform=linux/amd64 -t sqlserverft -f mssql-agent-fts-ha-tools.Dockerfile .`  command.

Answer (score 1):

I thought it was supported based on [this announcement](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/full-text-search-is-now-available-for-preview-in-azure-sql-database/), but it turns out it's in the ["unsupporteD" features list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql-edge/features#unsupported-features)